# $A$ is normal, and $B$ is Hermitian, why does $\left\| \rm{AB} \right\|{\rm{ = }}\left\| \rm{BA} \right\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $\left\| . \right\|$ be a unitarily invariant norm on $M_n$.

If $A, B ∈ M_n$, $A$ is normal, and $B$ is
Hermitian, why does $\left\| \rm{AB} \right\|{\rm{  =  }}\left\| \rm{BA} \right\|$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adjoint satisfies $\|C\| = \|C^*\|$.

An operator $A$ is normal **iff** $\|Ax\| = \|A^* x\|$ for all $x$.

Then $\|ABx\| = \|A^*Bx\|$ for all $x$, hence $\|AB\| = \|A^* B\|$, and
since $(A^*B)^* = B^* A = BA$, we have $\|AB\| = \|BA\|$.

Comment: $\|ABx\| = \|A^*Bx\|$ for all $x$, how does implied $\|AB\| = \|A^* B\|$?

Comment: @RaziehNoori: By definition of the norm: $\|C\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} \|Cx\|$.

Comment: but op has said  $\left\| . \right\|$ is a unitarily invariant norm on $M_n$. for example if  $\left\| . \right\|$ be schatten p-norm, what we can say?

Comment: Since we are talking Hermitian, normal, we must be in a Hilbert space. The norm must be compatible with the inner product. (At least, this is my interpretation!)